# Prove the max of convergent sequences of functions is convergent in $L^p$ space.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a measurable set, and $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Suppose $(f_n), (g_n)$ are two sequences in $L^p(E)$, $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(E)$, and $g_n \to g$ in $L^p(E)$. Prove that $h_n = \max\{f_n, g_n\}$ also converges in $L^p(E)$.

### Proof

Here, my goal is to prove that for $h$ defined as $h = \max\{f, g\}$ we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|h - h_n\|_{L^p(E)} = 0$$

So, break $E$ into the union of two disjoint sets 
\begin{align}
E &= E_{f_n}\cup E_{g_n}  \quad \text{where} \\ \\
E_{f_n} &= \{x \in E: f_n(x) >= g_n(x)\} \quad \text{and} \\ \\
 E_{g_n} &= \{x \in E: f_n(x) < g_n(x)\}
\end{align}

Then $E_{f_n}$ and $E_{g_n}$ must be measurable (don't know how to prove that) and we have $h_n = f_n$ on $E_{f_n}$ and $h_n = g_n$ on $E_{g_n}$. Therefore

\begin{align}
\left(\int_E \left|h_n\right|^p\right)^{1/p}  = \left(\int_{E_{f_n}}  \left|f_n\right|^p\right)^{1/p} + \left(\int_{E_{g_n}}  \left|g_n\right|^p \right)^{1/p}
\end{align}

which happens to show $h_n$  is in $L^p(E)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since $f_n, g_n$ are. If we take $\chi_{E_{f_n}}$ to be the characteristic function for $f_n$ (and similarly for $g_n$) we have

\begin{align}
\left(\int_E \left|h_n - h\right|^p\right)^{1/p}  &= \left(\int_{E}  \left|f_n - f\right|^p \chi_{E_{f_n}} \right)^{1/p} + \left(\int_{E}  \left|g_n - g\right|^p \chi_{E_{g_n}} \right)^{1/p} \\ \\
&\leq \left(\int_{E}  \left|f_n - f\right|^p \right)^{1/p} + \left(\int_{E}  \left|g_n - g\right|^p \right)^{1/p} 
\end{align}

where the inequality is due to the monotonicity of Lebesgue integrals. Here, by hypothesis, the right side goes to zero as $n \to +\infty$, so by the squeeze theorem, $h_n$ is convergent in $L^p(E)$.

### Discussion

The introduction of the characteristic function was unnecessary given monotonicity holds in the sense of sets and subsets so I could have just done that. Besides that, I'm still not sure if this proof is valid. I don't really have a good handle on what proof would be required to show a measurable set can be guaranteed to be broken into disjoint measurable sets with respect to the operation of max on measurable functions.

Another point that is required here, I believe is to show that the limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable. But I mean, how much stuff do I really have to prove to support this type of argument? Context -- functional analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much simpler argument: $\max \{f_n,g_n\}=\frac {f_n+g_n+|f_n-g_n|} 2$ so it is enough to show that $|f_n-g_n| \to |f-g|$. This follows from the fact that $||f_n-g_n|-|f-g||\leq |f_n-f|+|g_n-g|$ and $a^{p}+b^{p} \leq 2^{p} (a+b)$ for $a,b \geq 0$.